# VML line height. Any equivalent of SVG's dy attribute for text span (v:textpath)?

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, cross-browser, raphael, vml

What's the closest equivalent to `dy` in VML - the VML attribute that can be used to set the line height (aka line spacing, leading, vertical text offset...) of text elements?

Nothing in [the official docs for VML textpath stands out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb263924%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which makes me think that some other general y position based attribute is used. If so, it'd be good to also know how it's calculated and offset, e.g. in multi-line text, is it constant for each line, or increasing by a constant?

Why: for backwards browser compatibility of a Raphael project (javascript-based SVG / VML controller). Raphael doesn't support dy / line-height itself, so I need to work directly with the SVG / VML nodes it creates. SVG is easy: use `dy=pixels`. But I can't find any relevant docs or resources stating the VML equivalent, and I don't currently have access to IE to find it out by exploring VML ouput in internet explorer.

---

I thought this question might be as easy **[as opening up this jsfiddle in IE set to IE8 mode](http://jsfiddle.net/kgDNs/1/)**, and using Developer Tools to see what attribute sets the text line spacing. But, after getting access to a machine with IE, I found that... it's just odd. Nothing seems to change the line height, or, any other aspect of how the VML text is printed. No matter what I change, the text just doesn't budge. Can't figure it.

Comment: Any progress made on this?

Comment: Sadly  no,  there are a number  of  problems with  Raphael  text and I've  ended  up using parallel  Raphael/jQuery  to  use HTML  text  instead.  If you want to experiment  though this might be useful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17471380/how-to-debug-or-see-vml-ouput-in-ie-e-g-from-raphael